# Google shared contacts using contact api v3

Tags: google-contacts-api

Is it possible to add shared contacts using google contact api v3?
I have added contacts using domain shared contacts API, but this API causes duplicate contacts .
So google suggests to use contact api v3 .

Thank you in advance
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Creating contacts
To create a new contact, send an authorized POST request to the user's contacts feed URL with contact data in the body.

The URL is of the form:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full
```

With the appropriate value in place of userEmail.

Note: The special userEmail value default can be used to refer to the authenticated user.
Upon success, the server responds with an HTTP 201 Created status code and the created contact entry with some additional elements and properties (shown in bold) that are set by the server, such as id, various link elements and properties.

Comment: how do you send an authorized post